# Как сделать "жирными" элементы с тегом H2 Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть код для парсинга страницы:

```
Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(contentUrl).get();
                imagesRec = doc.select("div.post-featured-img amp-img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
                imgSrcUrl = imagesRec.attr("abs:src");

                contentPrepared = new StringBuilder();

                for (Element p : doc.select("div.amp-wp-article-content li, div.amp-wp-article-content p, div.amp-wp-article-content cite, div.amp-wp-article-content h2, div.amp-wp-article-content h3")) {
                    contentPrepared.append(p.text());
                    contentPrepared.append("\n" + "\n");
                }

                contentFinal = contentPrepared.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

В этой странице есть теги `H2` внутри класса `div.amp-wp-article-content`. Как мне выделить эти теги в коде и сделать текст, заключенный в них, жирным? Я еще не совсем понимаю, как мне проводить определенные манипуляции с тегами внутри страницы.

То есть задача в том, что в спарсенной странице все элементы с тегом `H2` сделать жирным и, соответственно, вывести весь получившийся текст в `TextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выделения определенного текста в textview попробуйте этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371107/7540461)

Можно выбрать с помощью jsoup нужный вам текст .html() произвести замену тега `<h2>...</h2> на <b>...</b>` также заменой убрать все остальные ненужные элементы по типу `<div>`

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду пробовать.

Comment: у меня получилось. Я заменил теги на те, которые мне нужны через replace("h2", "b"). Но теперь при выводе готового текста в TextView я получаю просто текст с измененными тегами, т.е. все равно не форматированный как нужно (без выделения жирным, курсивом и т д). Может можно как-то вывести отформатированный текст в TextView?

Comment: Все, сделал. Через вывод текста в TextView через Html.from